# Can I use OpenMP to do simple threaded tasks?

Tags: openmp

I am looking for a cross- platform C thread library to do things like:

launch a long-running thread, and in the thread, wait for an event to happen; when this event happens, do something, and then wait for the next event.

So, I don't need to do parallel computations, just simple  task in another thread.

Is it appropriate to use OpenMP for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, OpenMP is up to the task and is probably your most portable solution in C, albeit not the most elegant one in your particular use case.

OpenMP is based on the [fork-join model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork%E2%80%93join_model). You will thus need to fork somewhere in your code (using the `#pragma omp parallel` statement which launches threads) and then use an `if` to perform a particular task on the given thread. What you want to achieve could be done by something along the lines of:

```
#include <omp.h>

...

#pragma omp parallel num_threads(2)
{
    if (omp_get_thread_num() == 0) {
        [do something]
    } else {
        [do something else]
    }
}
```

With the description of your problem, you would for example perform this in your `main()` and replace `[do something]` by calls to various functions. One of these functions would be the loop you described in your question and the other one would be the rest of your program.

Depending on the nature of the event you talk about, you may have to define a shared variable in the `#pragma omp ...` statement to perform a basic inter-thread communication.

The way you described your problem seems a bit twisted though. Wouldn't it be simpler to develop two separate programs? (Depending on the nature of the event.)

Comment: As Soravux says, you can find a few ways to do this in OpenMP (tasks would be another way), but it's not the use case OpenMP was designed for, so it'll be awkward.  Roughly, OpenMP is designed for parallelism, where this case seems to be more about concurrency.  Pthreads, or C++11 threads, would probably be more natural.

Comment: Thanks very much, Soravux.  I do need this to happen in a single program. My use case is this: I have an image compression module that works asynchronously (using OpenCL language). I give it a file name, and it notifies me asynchronously when it has finished compression. So, I want the thread to listen for the finish event, and send over another file, while the main thread waits for exit.